# Django testing custom signal arguments with assertIsInstance: AssertionError: <class 'path.to.Foo'> is not an instance of <class 'path.to.Foo'>

Tags: python, django, python-unittest, django-testing, django-signals

I am using Django 3.2

I have written an app that raises custom events, and I am writing tests for the apps.

Here is the relevant section of my code:

```
class TestAppModel(TestCase):
    # .. set up instance variables etc.

    def test_liked_signal_emits_correct_data(self):
    
        self.signal_was_called = False
        self.sender = None
        self.instance = None   
        self.event_type = None
        self.actor = None

        def handler(sender, instance, event_type, actor, **kwargs):
            self.signal_was_called = True
            self.sender = sender
            self.instance = instance   
            self.event_type = event_type
            self.actor = actor         
            
        item_liked.connect(handler)

        self.daddy.like(self.admin_user)

 
        # Check that the sender is a Foo
        self.assertIsInstance(self.sender, Foo) # <- Nonsensical error emitted here
```

When I run the test, I get the error message:

> AssertionError: <class 'social.models.Foo'> is not an instance of <class 'social.models.Foo'>

Which obviously, is a nonsensical error message that doesn't help me solve the problem.

My question is why am I not able to check the instance type using `assertIsInstance`, and how do I check the class type in the signal receiver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `sender` in a signal is typically the *class* of the instance. Hence you writing `self.assertIsInstance(self.sender, Foo)` is equivalent to writing `self.assertIsInstance(Foo, Foo)` which of course is not correct as `Foo` is not an instance of `Foo` (It likely is an instance of `object`, `type` and `ModelBase` (metaclass of `Model`)). For instance see the following snippet:

```
class Foo:
    pass

print(isinstance(Foo, Foo)) # False
print(isinstance(Foo, object)) # True
print(isinstance(Foo, type)) # True
```

Instead you want to use `assertIs` instead of `assertIsInstance`:

```
class TestAppModel(TestCase):
    # .. set up instance variables etc.

    def test_liked_signal_emits_correct_data(self):
    
        self.signal_was_called = False
        self.sender = None
        self.instance = None   
        self.event_type = None
        self.actor = None

        def handler(sender, instance, event_type, actor, **kwargs):
            self.signal_was_called = True
            self.sender = sender
            self.instance = instance   
            self.event_type = event_type
            self.actor = actor         
            
        item_liked.connect(handler)

        self.daddy.like(self.admin_user)

 
        # Check that the sender is a Foo
        self.assertIs(self.sender, Foo) # The sender should be Foo itself
        self.assertIsInstance(self.instance, Foo) # The instance should be an instance of Foo
```

Comment: In the end, I was able to work out what was going on, and I rewrote this using a ContextManger class that wraps around a mock object - but thanks for your answer as always!

Comment: @HomunculusReticulli I would like to complement your questions though, you always have a proper mre in your question. :)